# Create new project asp.net mvc and run the application header cannot display

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help me. To start with I'm a beginner. T^T
I created new project asp.net mvc and run the application. 
Why can header in the red circle not display like this second photo?

**Image 1**:
[image: Browser Screenshot]
**Image 2**:
[image: Browser Screenshot]

Comment: Certainly because both code are differents.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing scripts, Mvc uses bootstrap as default, As you can see you do not have even navigation. Maby jquery.

Check console logs and network.